# What is Difference Between Left Joining and outer joining?

Tags: sql

What is Difference Between Left Joining and outer joining .can any one explain with example??

Comment: No difference, it's just optional syntax: `LEFT|RIGHT|FULL [OUTER] JOIN`, similar to the optional `[INNER] JOIN`

Comment: A left join is a type of outer join.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference: A `left join` *is* an outer join.

A `right join` is also an outer join, but I've never seen one used commerically.

Comment: It's funny you mention this. I recently rewrote several mind-bending right JOINs on a project. It was bizarre SQL previously generated by a modeling tool (I'm looking at you, Management Studio View Designer). I have also never seen RIGHT JOIN used for any productive reason.